# SDWebImage caching fails when loading big number of images

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I'm using `SDWebImageDownloader.shared().downloadImage` to download images, then

```
if let i = image {
    let key = SDWebImageManager.shared().cacheKey(for: product.imageURL)
    SDImageCache.shared().store(i, forKey: key, completion: nil)
}
```

My code iterates on a product array, and downloads all the images for them (so it will appear while the user is only even if the product's page wasn't opened before)

My problem is, that it doesn't save the images at all, I see a bunch of these in the log:

```
CFNetwork internal error (0xc01a:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-811.5.4/Loading/URLConnectionLoader.cpp:304)
```

Could you please give me a hint where to start?

Thanks!

Comment: Where to start: Create a simple app to download and save **ONE** image. If you can get that to work, set a breakpoint in your full app where you are "iterating on a product array" and check that you are getting the values you are expecting. Then step through line-by-line to find the error.

Comment: The strange thing is that other images are saved with the same method, maybe the problem is that I want to download about 1500 images at once?

Comment: Hard to say... I'm familiar with SDWebImage, but I don't use it. You'd need to run some "load testing" --- 100 images, then 250, 500, etc. See if/when you hit a limit.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that, thanks!